# Python - convert strings into json and combine

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I h've two strings got from an api url

```
pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(ariel_url+"?%s"  % params1)
data1 = pagehandle.read(); 
pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(ariel_url+"?%s"  % params2)
data2 = pagehandle.read();
```

data1 and data2 contain the following `string`

```
{"priority":"HIGH", "titles":["Brand", "Likes"], "values":[["addidas", 130],["nike", 180]]}

{"priority":"HIGH", "titles":["Brand", "Likes"], "values":[["iphone", 49],["ipod", 590]]}
```

I want to convert these two strings into json and combine (or combine strings and then convert) in such a way that output json may like

```
{"priority":"HIGH", "titles":["Brand", "Likes"], "values":[["addidas", 130],["nike", 180],["iphone", 49],["ipod", 590]]]}
```

How can i do this? i prefer to use simplejson library

Comment: Why would you use *any* JSON library? Python is quite competent at handling its own datatypes.

Comment: the `value` property name should be quoted, right?!

Comment: It would help ENORMOUSLY if you said where/how you got those two "strings": are they already JSON strings (in which case "convert ... into json" needs explanation) or are they `repr(a_Python_dict)` (in which case why don't you omit the repr() and just use the dicts?) or something else ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not strings, but dictionaries. You can combine those dictionary like this:

```
def combine(dict1, dict2):
    if dict1['priority'] == dict2['priority'] and dict1['titles'] == dict2['titles']:
        return {
            'priority': dict1['priority'],
            'titles': dict1['titles'],
            'values': dict1['values'] + dict2['values']
        }
```

after that you simply run:

```
import json
json.dumps(combine(dict1, dict2))
```

and you'll get a json of those two combined dictionaries.

**EDIT**

So I understand is what you really got is:

```
s1 = '{"priority":"HIGH", "titles":["Brand", "Likes"], values:[["addidas", 130],["nike", 180]]}'

s2 = '{"priority":"HIGH", "titles":["Brand", "Likes"], values:[["iphone", 49],["ipod", 590]]}'
```

In this case you can run:

```
dict1 = json.loads(s1)
dict2 = json.loads(s2)
result = combine(dict1, dict2)
```

Comment: sorry these are strings got from a remote URL and the Python native dictionaries

Comment: @Mithun P: Edit your question with that information. Please also tell us how you can get each string from a remote URL and from "the Python native dictionaries" simultaneously.

Comment: Your `combine()` function is equivalent to `lambda combine dict1, dict2: None`

Comment: @John Machin: True, I have added a return. Thanks.

Comment: @John Machin, sorry both are strings, i missed the 'not' in my comment. Read "sorry these are strings got from a remote URL and NOT the Python native dictionaries" - can somebody edit that and correct ..?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
import json
a = json.loads('{"priority":"HIGH", "titles":["Brand", "Likes"], "values":[["addidas", 130],["nike", 180]]}')
b = json.loads('{"priority":"HIGH", "titles":["Brand", "Likes"], "values":[["iphone", 49],["ipod", 590]]}')

for value in a['values']:
   b['values'].append(value)

# edited
json.dumps(b)
```

Comment: you missed the `json.dumps(b)` part ;-)